# Error Rendering an Array of Custom Components in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to render an array of (custom-built) React Native components, but I am getting the following error when I try to do so:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of 'CategoryList'.

I have a component called `CategoryList` (which is a stateless component), and it renders a collection of `Category` components. They are defined below:

`CategoryList`:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import View from 'react-native';
import humps from 'humps';
import Category from './Category';

const CategoryList = ({ categories }) => {
  const camelizedCategories = humps.camelizeKeys(categories);
  const categoryElements = camelizedCategories.map(
    (category, idx) => <Category {...category} key={idx} />
  );

  return (
    <View>
      {categoryElements}
    </View>
  );
};

CategoryList.propTypes = {
  categories: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      display_name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      list_name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      list_name_encoded: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      newest_published_date: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      oldest_published_date: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      updated: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    })
  ),
};

export default CategoryList;
```

`Category`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Category = ({
  displayName,
  listName,
  listNameEncoded,
  newestPublishedDate,
  oldestPublishedDate,
  updated,
}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {displayName}
      </Text>
      <Text>
        {listName}
        {listNameEncoded}
      </Text>
      <Text>
        {listNameEncoded}
      </Text>
      <Text>
        {newestPublishedDate}
      </Text>
      <Text>
        {oldestPublishedDate}
      </Text>
      <Text>
        {updated}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

Category.propTypes = {
  displayName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  listName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  listNameEncoded: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  newestPublishedDate: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  oldestPublishedDate: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  updated: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Category;
```

Finally, categories is being called as follows:

```
<CategoryList categories={mockedData} />
```

Where `mockedData` is being defined as follows:

```
const mockedData = [
  {
    list_name: 'Combined Print and E-Book Fiction',
    display_name: 'Combined Print & E-Book Fiction',
    list_name_encoded: 'combined-print-and-e-book-fiction',
    oldest_published_date: '2011-02-13',
    newest_published_date: '2016-08-21',
    updated: 'WEEKLY',
  },
  {
    list_name: 'Combined Print and E-Book Nonfiction',
    display_name: 'Combined Print & E-Book Nonfiction',
    list_name_encoded: 'combined-print-and-e-book-nonfiction',
    oldest_published_date: '2011-02-13',
    newest_published_date: '2016-08-21',
    updated: 'WEEKLY',
  },
];
```

Comment: What happens if you make `CategoryList` to return an empty view, kinda like `const CategoryList = _ => <View />`? do you still get the same error?

Comment: Nabn, no error when I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if `import View from 'react-native'` in `CategoryList` is a typo in question.
Should be `import {View} from 'react-native'`

Comment: this is embarrassing. It was indeed a typo. I didn't pay too close attention to this because my linter usually tells me if it can't import something. It must import something, but obviously not what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

If categories is empty, categoryElements is an empty array.

```
const categoryElements = camelizedCategories.map(
    (category, idx) => <Category {...category} key={idx} />
  );
```

Instead, the code should be:

```
const categoryElements = camelizedCategories.length > 0 ? camelizedCategories.map(
    (category, idx) => <Category {...category} key={idx} />
  ) : null;
```